# Does aria-haspopup require a true/false value?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#aria-haspopup), the value should be a boolean. However, one of the [spec examples of proper implementation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html) uses a string value other than true/false - "listbox", which is the value of another element's role attribute. Is this a flaw in the implementation example or do screen readers, in practice, gain additional information from values other than true?

Relevant code from linked example:

```
<div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="ex1-listbox" aria-haspopup="listbox" id="ex1-combobox">
    <input type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="ex1-listbox" id="ex1-input" aria-activedescendant="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally (WAI-ARIA 1.0), `aria-haspopup` could only be true/false.  But WAI-ARIA 1.1 added additional values.  You can still use true/false but you can also be more specific about what kind of popup the element will have (a menu, a tree, a grid, a listbox, etc).

Answer (score 1):

## W3 specifications

If the w3 spec says its value can be true or false, then that is what browsers will be implementing.
If the attribute accepts other values, its undefined behavior. Avoid this if possible.

Some times the values of accepted attributes will change over the different versions of the w3 specification.

Comment: I don't disagree that following the spec is, in general, good advise. However, from what I understand browsers don't really implement anything specific for the aria-haspopup attribute. It's more for the benefit of screen readers, and sometimes vendors deviate from the spec when it adds value. Nevertheless, I will accept this answer if nobody addresses this point directly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found myself reading an older version of the spec. [This version](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-haspopup) was the correct one, and it contains the newer options.